# Use youtube-dl to download directly to S3

Tags: python, amazon-s3

I am trying to write a lambda function (ultimately) that writes the output of `youtube-dl` directly to S3. The way I've had to prototype this is to dump the output to `stdout` and then redirect that to a file in S3, but this seems like a massive hack.

```
import youtube_dl, sys
from smart_open import open
from contextlib import redirect_stdout

ydl_opts = { 'outtmpl': '-', 'cachedir': False, 'logtostderr': True }
with youtube_dl.YoutubeDL(ydl_opts) as ydl:
  with open('s3://<test-bucket>/test.mp4','wb') as f:
    with redirect_stdout(f): 
      ydl.download(['https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zzEYsi_P0RU'])
```

Does anyone else have a magic idea?

Comment: does boto not provide the functionality you need?

Comment: https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/guide/s3-uploading-files.html

Comment: Can't you download the file to `/tmp/` and then upload to Amazon S3 using boto3?

Comment: I can't save to disk because I've got unknown file lengths and only a small amount of disk space available in the Lambda. I want to just stream it over to S3 to not have to deal with storing it locally. `smart_open` uses boto3.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this using nodejs streams, as long as you can finish the task with in a maximum of 15 minutes as the lambda task will timeout beyond that.

1. Create a PassThrough stream in Node.js. A pass-through stream is a duplex stream where you can write on one side and read on the other side.

```
   const stream = require('stream');
   const passthrough = new stream.PassThrough();
```

2. Write data to the stream using the youtube-dl library.

```
   const youtubedl = require('youtube-dl');
   const dl = youtubedl(event.videoUrl, ['--format=best[ext=mp4]'], 
              {maxBuffer: Infinity});
   dl.pipe(passtrough); // write video to the pass-through stream
```

3. Finally, upload the stream to S3. You can make use of the Multipart Upload feature of S3 which allows us to upload a big file in smaller chunks. This means you only have to buffer the small junk (64 MB in this case) in memory and not the whole file.

```
  const AWS = require('aws-sdk');
  const upload = new AWS.S3.ManagedUpload({
    params: {
      Bucket: process.env.BUCKET_NAME,
      Key: 'video.mp4',
      Body: passtrough
    },
   partSize: 1024 * 1024 * 64 // 64 MB in bytes
  });
 upload.send((err) => {
    if (err) {
      console.log('error', err);
    } else {
     console.log('done');
   }
  });
```

Try to provide enough resources to the lambda like a large amount of memory for better network performance.